# How to Increase Performance of Manipulate Recalculating List?

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, performance-tuning

I have a list in the form of `prices` below.

```
mcd = FinancialData["MCD", {{1990, 1, 1}, {2014, 1, 1}, "Month"}];
ibm = FinancialData["IBM", {{1990, 1, 1}, {2014, 1, 1}, "Month"}, 
 "Value"];
hpq = FinancialData["HPQ", {{1990, 1, 1}, {2014, 1, 1}, "Month"}, 
 "Value"];
prices = Table[
 Append[hpq[[i]]]@Append[ibm[[i]]]@mcd[[i]], 
 {i, First@Dimensions[ibm]}];
```

I have `prices` in this form and am not building it from `FinancialData`.  From this I make a `DataListLogPlot` that I'd like to reindex to certain points using `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 DateListPlot[
  Table[
   Table[
    {
     prices[[i, 1]],
     Table[100 (prices[[m, n]]/prices[[indexLoc, n]]), 
      {m, 1, Dimensions[prices][[1]]}, {n, 2, 4}][[i, j]]
    },
    {i, Dimensions[prices][[1]]}],
   {j, Dimensions[prices][[2]] - 1}],
  GridLines -> {None, Automatic}, PlotLegends -> Automatic
 ],
{indexLoc, 1, Dimensions[prices][[1]], 12}]
```

This works.  It reindexes the values to 100 at the month in the series that is selected by the slider.  However, it takes a while (4 seconds or so) to calculate each time it is moved.  I was hoping to have this scrollable with a vertical line at the month it is reindex.  However, it is too clunky with this 4 second lag. Is there a way to speed this up?  I looked at a few of the time series functions but nothing jumped out at me.

Thanks,

Edmund

---

**Update**

From Sander's suggestion below I was able to get to what I wanted.  I need to keep it as a `DateListLogPlot` but was able to use `Transpose` to get there.

```
(*Using the "prices" variable from above*)
plotPrices =
  Table[
   Table[
    {
     prices[[i, 1]],
     Table[(prices[[m, n]]), {m, 1, Dimensions[prices][[1]]}, 
      {n, 2, 4}][[i, j]]
    },
   {i, Dimensions[prices][[1]]}],
  {j, Dimensions[prices][[2]] - 1}];

Manipulate[
 DateListLogPlot[
  Transpose[
   {#[[All, 1]], 100 #[[All, 2]]/#[[indexLoc, 2]]} & /@ plotPrices, 
   {1, 3, 2}], 
  GridLines -> {None, Automatic}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic],
 {indexLoc, 1, Dimensions[prices][[1]], 1}]
```

Comment: Changed step size to 12.  Had it too large from when I was trying things to speed it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance issue is that you are dynamically building several levels of tables into tables into a plot function into a manipulate.

This is very slow and what you are looking for is to **build** the table outside the plot and outside the manipulate and only do the indexation inside.

**However (!!)** it seems to me there is a very straightforward solution to what you want to achieve, and avoid the table creation altogether.

Performance on my Macbook Pro i7 is much faster: approx 0.0003 seconds per manipulation.

> > ```
> > mcd = FinancialData["MCD", {{1990, 1, 1}, {2014, 1, 1}, "Month"}];
> > ibm = FinancialData["IBM", {{1990, 1, 1}, {2014, 1, 1}, "Month"}];
> > hpq = FinancialData["HPQ", {{1990, 1, 1}, {2014, 1, 1}, "Month"}];
> > Manipulate[ListLinePlot[100 #[[All, 2]]/#[[ix, 2]] & /@ {mcd, ibm, hpq}], {ix, 1, Length[mcd], 1}]
> > ```

Hope this is what you are looking for. Please note I made the data format for mdc,ivm and hpq consistent.

Comment: This put me on track get the answer I was looking for.  Thanks!  I still need it to be a `DateListPlot` (actually a `DateListLogPlot`) but I was able to get there from here with `Transpose`.

Comment: You are most welcome; I liked your question btw.